# Text you cant delete in text area

Tags: html, textarea

Hi I have a text area with a table inside it. I would like to make it so that the user can not delete the table but can add to it. Can I do this with HTML? Thanks.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow..:) read this before starting anything http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it only with textarea configuration, but you can print (`within <p> tag` or something else), the current text, add to the empty textarea and design it look as you want with CSS.